# Failed to get job complete status for job rke-network-plugin-deploy-job

Tags: kubernetes, rancher, rke

I depolied rke in air-gapped environment with below specification:

---

Nodes:

3 controller with etcd
2 workers

---

RKE version: 
v1.0.0

---

Docker version:

```
Client:
Debug Mode: false
Server:
Containers: 24
Running: 7
Paused: 0
Stopped: 17
Images: 4
Server Version: 19.03.1-ol
Storage Driver: overlay2
Backing Filesystem: xfs
Supports d_type: true
Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
Volume: local
Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: **************
runc version: ******
init version: fec3683
Security Options:
seccomp
Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.14.35-1902.8.4.el7uek.x86_64
Operating System: Oracle Linux Server 7.7
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 1.409GiB
Name: rke01.kuberlocal.co
ID:*******************************
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode: false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
registry.console:5000
127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
Registries:
```

---

Operating system and kernel: (Oracle linux 7)

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.7
4.14.35-1902.8.4.el7uek.x86_64
```

---

Type/provider of hosts: VirtualBox (test environment)

---

cluster.yml file:

```
If you intened to deploy Kubernetes in an air-gapped environment,
please consult the documentation on how to configure custom RKE images.

nodes:

    address: rke01
    port: "22"
    internal_address: 192.168.40.11
    role:
        controlplane
        etcd
        hostname_override: ""
        user: rke
        docker_socket: /var/run/docker.sock
        ssh_key: ""
        ssh_key_path: ~/.ssh/id_rsa
        ssh_cert: ""
        ssh_cert_path: ""
        labels: {}
        taints: []
    address: rke02
    port: "22"
    internal_address: 192.168.40.17
    role:
        controlplane
        etcd
        hostname_override: ""
        user: rke
        docker_socket: /var/run/docker.sock
        ssh_key: ""
        ssh_key_path: ~/.ssh/id_rsa
        ssh_cert: ""
        ssh_cert_path: ""
        labels: {}
        taints: []
    address: rke03
    port: "22"
    internal_address: 192.168.40.13
    role:
        controlplane
        etcd
        hostname_override: ""
        user: rke
        docker_socket: /var/run/docker.sock
        ssh_key: ""
        ssh_key_path: ~/.ssh/id_rsa
        ssh_cert: ""
        ssh_cert_path: ""
        labels: {}
        taints: []
    address: rke04
    port: "22"
    internal_address: 192.168.40.14
    role:
        worker
        hostname_override: ""
        user: rke
        docker_socket: /var/run/docker.sock
        ssh_key: ""
        ssh_key_path: ~/.ssh/id_rsa
        ssh_cert: ""
        ssh_cert_path: ""
        labels: {}
        taints: []
    address: rke05
    port: "22"
    internal_address: 192.168.40.15
    role:
        worker
        hostname_override: ""
        user: rke
        docker_socket: /var/run/docker.sock
        ssh_key: ""
        ssh_key_path: ~/.ssh/id_rsa
        ssh_cert: ""
        ssh_cert_path: ""
        labels: {}
        taints: []
        services:
        etcd:
        image: ""
        extra_args: {}
        extra_binds: []
        extra_env: []
        external_urls: []
        ca_cert: ""
        cert: ""
        key: ""
        path: ""
        uid: 0
        gid: 0
        snapshot: null
        retention: ""
        creation: ""
        backup_config: null
        kube-api:
        image: ""
        extra_args: {}
        extra_binds: []
        extra_env: []
        service_cluster_ip_range: 10.43.0.0/16
        service_node_port_range: ""
        pod_security_policy: false
        always_pull_images: false
        secrets_encryption_config: null
        audit_log: null
        admission_configuration: null
        event_rate_limit: null
        kube-controller:
        image: ""
        extra_args: {}
        extra_binds: []
        extra_env: []
        cluster_cidr: 10.42.0.0/16
        service_cluster_ip_range: 10.43.0.0/16
        scheduler:
        image: ""
        extra_args: {}
        extra_binds: []
        extra_env: []
        kubelet:
        image: ""
        extra_args: {}
        extra_binds: []
        extra_env: []
        cluster_domain: bmi.rke.cluster.local
        infra_container_image: ""
        cluster_dns_server: 10.43.0.10
        fail_swap_on: false
        generate_serving_certificate: false
        kubeproxy:
        image: ""
        extra_args: {}
        extra_binds: []
        extra_env: []
        network:
        plugin: weave
        weave_network_provider:
        password: "********"
        options: {}
        node_selector: {}
        authentication:
        strategy: x509
        sans: []
        webhook: null
        addons: ""
        addons_include: []
        system_images:
        etcd: registry.console:5000/rancher/coreos-etcd:v3.3.15-rancher1
        alpine: registry.console:5000/rancher/rke-tools:v0.1.51
        nginx_proxy: registry.console:5000/rancher/rke-tools:v0.1.51
        cert_downloader: registry.console:5000/rancher/rke-tools:v0.1.51
        kubernetes_services_sidecar: registry.console:5000/rancher/rke-tools:v0.1.51
        kubedns: registry.console:5000/rancher/k8s-dns-kube-dns:1.15.0
        dnsmasq: registry.console:5000/rancher/k8s-dns-dnsmasq-nanny:1.15.0
        kubedns_sidecar: registry.console:5000/rancher/k8s-dns-sidecar:1.15.0
        kubedns_autoscaler: registry.console:5000/rancher/cluster-proportional-autoscaler:1.7.1
        coredns: registry.console:5000/rancher/coredns-coredns:1.6.2
        coredns_autoscaler: registry.console:5000/rancher/cluster-proportional-autoscaler:1.7.1
        kubernetes: registry.console:5000/rancher/hyperkube:v1.16.3-rancher1
        flannel: registry.console:5000/rancher/coreos-flannel:v0.11.0-rancher1
        flannel_cni: registry.console:5000/rancher/flannel-cni:v0.3.0-rancher5
        calico_node: registry.console:5000/rancher/calico-node:v3.8.1
        calico_cni: registry.console:5000/rancher/calico-cni:v3.8.1
        calico_controllers: registry.console:5000/rancher/calico-kube-controllers:v3.8.1
        calico_ctl: ""
        calico_flexvol: registry.console:5000/rancher/calico-pod2daemon-flexvol:v3.8.1
        canal_node: registry.console:5000/rancher/calico-node:v3.8.1
        canal_cni: registry.console:5000/rancher/calico-cni:v3.8.1
        canal_flannel: registry.console:5000/rancher/coreos-flannel:v0.11.0
        canal_flexvol: registry.console:5000/rancher/calico-pod2daemon-flexvol:v3.8.1
        weave_node: registry.console:5000/weaveworks/weave-kube:2.5.2
        weave_cni: registry.console:5000/weaveworks/weave-npc:2.5.2
        pod_infra_container: registry.console:5000/rancher/pause:3.1
        ingress: registry.console:5000/rancher/nginx-ingress-controller:nginx-0.25.1-rancher1
        ingress_backend: registry.console:5000/rancher/nginx-ingress-controller-defaultbackend:1.5-rancher1
        metrics_server: registry.console:5000/rancher/metrics-server:v0.3.4
        windows_pod_infra_container: rancher/kubelet-pause:v0.1.3
        ssh_key_path: ~/.ssh/id_rsa
        ssh_cert_path: ""
        ssh_agent_auth: false
        authorization:
        mode: rbac
        options: {}
        #ignore_docker_version: false
        ignore_docker_version: true
        kubernetes_version: ""
        private_registries:
            url: registry.console:5000
            user: registry_user
            password: ***********
            is_default: true
            ingress:
            provider: ""
            options: {}
            node_selector: {}
            extra_args: {}
            dns_policy: ""
            extra_envs: []
            extra_volumes: []
            extra_volume_mounts: []
            cluster_name: ""
            cloud_provider:
            name: ""
            prefix_path: "/opt/rke/"
            addon_job_timeout: 30
            bastion_host:
            address: ""
            port: ""
            user: ""
            ssh_key: ""
            ssh_key_path: ""
            ssh_cert: ""
            ssh_cert_path: ""
            monitoring:
            provider: ""
            options: {}
            node_selector: {}
            restore:
            restore: false
            snapshot_name: ""
            dns:
            provider: coredns
```

---

Steps to Reproduce:

```
rke -d up --config cluster.yml
```

---

Results:

```
INFO[0129] [sync] Successfully synced nodes Labels and Taints
DEBU[0129] Host: rke01 has role: controlplane
DEBU[0129] Host: rke01 has role: etcd
DEBU[0129] Host: rke03 has role: controlplane
DEBU[0129] Host: rke03 has role: etcd
DEBU[0129] Host: rke04 has role: worker
DEBU[0129] Host: rke05 has role: worker
INFO[0129] [network] Setting up network plugin: weave
INFO[0129] [addons] Saving ConfigMap for addon rke-network-plugin to Kubernetes
INFO[0129] [addons] Successfully saved ConfigMap for addon rke-network-plugin to Kubernetes
INFO[0129] [addons] Executing deploy job rke-network-plugin
DEBU[0129] [k8s] waiting for job rke-network-plugin-deploy-job to complete..
FATA[0159] Failed to get job complete status for job rke-network-plugin-deploy-job in namespace kube-system
```

---

kubectl get pods --all-namespaces

```
NAMESPACE NAME READY STATUS RESTARTS AGE
kube-system rke-network-plugin-deploy-job-4jgcq 0/1 Error 0 4m6s
kube-system rke-network-plugin-deploy-job-57jr8 0/1 Error 0 3m50s
kube-system rke-network-plugin-deploy-job-h2gr8 0/1 Error 0 90s
kube-system rke-network-plugin-deploy-job-p92br 0/1 Error 0 2m50s
kube-system rke-network-plugin-deploy-job-xrgpl 0/1 Error 0 4m1s
kube-system rke-network-plugin-deploy-job-zqhmk 0/1 Error 0 3m30s
```

---

kubectl describe pod rke-network-plugin-deploy-job-zqhmk -n kube-system

```
Name: rke-network-plugin-deploy-job-zqhmk
Namespace: kube-system
Priority: 0
Node: rke01/192.168.40.11
Start Time: Sun, 12 Jan 2020 09:40:00 +0330
Labels: controller-uid=*******************
job-name=rke-network-plugin-deploy-job
Annotations:
Status: Failed
IP: 192.168.40.11
IPs:
IP: 192.168.40.11
Controlled By: Job/rke-network-plugin-deploy-job
Containers:
rke-network-plugin-pod:
Container ID: docker://7658aecff174e4ac53caaf088782dab50654911065371cd0d8dcdd50b8fbef3b
Image: registry.console:5000/rancher/hyperkube:v1.16.3-rancher1
Image ID: docker-pullable://registry.console:5000/rancher/hyperkube@sha256:0a55590eb8453bcc46a4bdb8217a48cf56a7c7f7c52d72a267632ffa35b3b8c8
Port:
Host Port:
Command:
kubectl
apply
-f
/etc/config/rke-network-plugin.yaml
State: Terminated
Reason: Error
Exit Code: 1
Started: Sun, 12 Jan 2020 09:40:00 +0330
Finished: Sun, 12 Jan 2020 09:40:01 +0330
Ready: False
Restart Count: 0
Environment:
Mounts:
/etc/config from config-volume (rw)
/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from rke-job-deployer-token-9dt6n (ro)
Conditions:
Type Status
Initialized True
Ready False
ContainersReady False
PodScheduled True
Volumes:
config-volume:
Type: ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
Name: rke-network-plugin
Optional: false
rke-job-deployer-token-9dt6n:
Type: Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
SecretName: rke-job-deployer-token-9dt6n
Optional: false
QoS Class: BestEffort
Node-Selectors:
Tolerations:
Events:
Type Reason Age From Message

Normal Pulled 4m10s kubelet, rke01 Container image "registry.console:5000/rancher/hyperkube:v1.16.3-rancher1" already present on machine
Normal Created 4m10s kubelet, rke01 Created container rke-network-plugin-pod
Normal Started 4m10s kubelet, rke01 Started container rke-network-plugin-pod
```

---

container logs:
docker logs -f 267a894bb999

```
unable to recognize "/etc/config/rke-network-plugin.yaml": Get https://10.43.0.1:443/api?timeout=32s: dial tcp 10.43.0.1:443: connect: network is unreachable
unable to recognize "/etc/config/rke-network-plugin.yaml": Get https://10.43.0.1:443/api?timeout=32s: dial tcp 10.43.0.1:443: connect: network is unreachable
unable to recognize "/etc/config/rke-network-plugin.yaml": Get https://10.43.0.1:443/api?timeout=32s: dial tcp 10.43.0.1:443: connect: network is unreachable
unable to recognize "/etc/config/rke-network-plugin.yaml": Get https://10.43.0.1:443/api?timeout=32s: dial tcp 10.43.0.1:443: connect: network is unreachable
unable to recognize "/etc/config/rke-network-plugin.yaml": Get https://10.43.0.1:443/api?timeout=32s: dial tcp 10.43.0.1:443: connect: network is unreachable
unable to recognize "/etc/config/rke-network-plugin.yaml": Get https://10.43.0.1:443/api?timeout=32s: dial tcp 10.43.0.1:443: connect: network is unreachable
```

---

network interfaces

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether *********** brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 192.168.40.11/24 brd 192.168.40.255 scope global dynamic enp0s8
valid_lft 847sec preferred_lft 847sec
inet6 ************* scope link
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
link/ether *************** brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ************* scope link
valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

---

### docker network status

docker network ls

```
NETWORK ID NAME DRIVER SCOPE
c6063ba5a4d0 bridge bridge local
822441eae3cf host host local
314798c82599 none null local
```

is the issue related to network interfaces? if yes: how can i create it?

Comment: that's resolved by below command and I created a network interface:


docker network create --driver=bridge --subnet=10.43.0.0/16 br0_rke

Comment: Please post an answer with your solution and details.

Answer (score 1):

that's resolved by below command and I created a network interface:

```
docker network create --driver=bridge --subnet=10.43.0.0/16 br0_rke
```

Comment: yeah, but this would mean that RKE is broken

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and these two steps solved my problem.

1. Increase `addon_job_timeout`
2. Check node free space (at lease 15%)

In my case, one of the nodes had `DiskPressure` state

Answer (score 0):

I creating Ubuntu vms in the local machine and having this problem. I got it working by increasing the disk and memory capacities at VM creation. `multipass launch --name node1 -m 2G -d 8G`.